# Deserialize в C#

Tags: c#, json

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, никак не могу понять `Deserialize` в *C#*.
Мне нужно из файла **.json** считать в объект класса данные и вывести на экран.

```
public void GetPerson()
{
    var PesonJson = File.ReadAllText("Person.json");
    Person person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(PesonJson);
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

Выдает исключение:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 
> "The JSON value could not be converted to JsonApp.Model.Person. Path: 
> $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Json файл

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Tom",
    "Age": 37
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jhon",
    "Age": 28
  },
  {
    "Name": "Emma",
    "Age": 29
  },
  {
    "Name": "Shara",
    "Age": 39
  }
]
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `Что делаю ни так?` - это вы нам скажите, что у вас там не так. Пока мы видим лишь вызов метода, без JSON, без класса, без вообще какой либо информации...

Comment: Какое исключение бросается, что выводится на экран, предоставьте объект **Person**, Покажите ваш **.json** файл.

Comment: Вызов метода?  Какого? Writeline? 
JSon файл лежит в корне программы.

Comment: Вам исключение напрямую говорит что у вам ошибка в структуре **.json** файла, может быть вы его нам покажите ?

Comment: Уважаемый, вы задаете вопрос связанный с JSON, но его нам не показываете. Также ваш вопрос очень тесно связан с классом `Person`, который вы также нам не показываете. Вы сами сможете ответить на аналогичный вопрос? Ну вот к примеру "Холодильник не работает, что делать?" вы ведь не знаете какого вида холодильник, его марка, его характеристики, вы не знаете как конкретно себя он проявляет и так далее, а значит, пока вы это не узнаете - проблему не решить. Также и тут, вы просите у незнакомых людей помощи, но ничего не говорите о проблеме. В **ваших** интересах дать нам **всю* информацию.

Comment: Много комментариев и ни одного толкового совета.

Comment: Уважаемый, а можно сбавить обороты?
У меня такое чуство как будто я тут прошу у вам милион долоров. Не хотите отвечать проходите мимо. Тут вроде за помощью обращаются а не для того,  с людьми в таком тоне говорить. 
JSon  формировался из программы при помощи такого же класса Person.
Вот и содержание файла .json. 
[
  {
    "Name": "Tom",
    "Age": 37
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jhon",
    "Age": 28
  },
  {
    "Name": "Emma",
    "Age": 29
  },
  {
    "Name": "Shara",
    "Age": 39
  }
]

Comment: вот содержание класса

  public class Person
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
  }

Думаю вам мало это поможет что бы ответить на мой вопрос....

Comment: А, так у вас массив Person.

Comment: Хм, а я набирал обороты?) Я вас изначально прошу дать **всю** нужную информацию, без претензий и прочего. Я вам даже дал пример, чтоб вы поняли почему я прошу эти данные. Не расценивайте много текста сразу каким-то триггером на агр. Вот вы дали класс и JSON, сразу видно что вы пихаете массив (в JSON он помечается как`[]`) в один конкретный класс, когда как должно быть `Person[]` (массив персон). Видите, сразу ответы пошли, ну а без этих данных на вопрос просто невозможно дать ответ, ибо в JSON и в классе у вас может быть что угодно. На будущее, пожалуйста, все данные сразу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для понимания, что происходит, выполните этот код:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void GetPerson() {
        var PesonJson = File.ReadAllText("Person.json");
        Person person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(PesonJson);
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
    static void PutPerson() {
        File.WriteAllText("Person.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize<Person>(new Person() { Name = "Oleg" }));
    }
    static void Main() {
        PutPerson();
        GetPerson();
    }
}
```

Код создаёт экземпляр класса Person и сохраняет его JSONом в файл, а потом читает оттуда.

Подставьте своё определение класса Person. После выполнения посмотрите содержимое файла "Person.json".

У вас проблема в том, что в файле список или массив Person, который нужно читать так:

```
Person[] persons = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person[]>(PesonJson);
Console.WriteLine(persons[0].Name);
```